# Format "2019-08-12T12:10:13Z" to datetime "2019-08-12 12:10:13" in Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, format

We're working on Node-red, where we have a javascript function, where we need to format a datetime looking like this: "2019-08-12T12:10:13Z". The datetime needs to be formatted to "2019-08-12 12:10:13" as we want to store the datetime in our MySQL database as timestamp.

Basically, what we want to do, is to remove the T and Z from the datetime.

This should be fairly easy to do, but we can't find anything on this for javascript.

**IMPRORTANT EDIT**

Just read that Z stands for UTC, and as we're living in CEST, we want to convert the timezone from UTC to CEST...

Comment: "T" and "Z" are there for a reason, because the kind of format we're talking about is an ISO compliant date string. I doubt you couldn't find anything on the entire network about this, I'm just here to point out that it's likely an X-Y question, you would better understand why "T" and "Z" are there for, before trying to understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: `"2019-08-12T12:10:13Z".replace(/(T|Z$)/g," ").trim()`

Comment: Thanks, @VadimHulevich. We also want to convert the timezone from UTC to CEST. Do you know how?

Comment: What about `new Date("2019-08-12T12:10:13Z").toLocaleString()`

Comment: If you use the package [mysql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql). You don't need to stringify Date objects. So you could pass a `new Date('2019-08-12T12:10:13Z')` object to the query function.

Comment: Thanks a lot! We use var "datetime = new Date('2019-08-12T12:10:13Z').toLocaleString();" but the time is printed as "2019-8-12 12:10:13" not not "2019-08-12 12:10:13". Can we convert it so month is 08 instead?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a special formated Date you have to use library like [moment](https://momentjs.com/) or format it yourself.

```js
const getFormattedDate = (date) => {
  return `${date.getFullYear()}-${padNumber(date.getMonth() + 1)}-${padNumber(date.getDate())} ${padNumber(date.getHours())}:${padNumber(date.getMinutes())}:${padNumber(date.getSeconds())}`;
}

const padNumber = (number) => {
  return number < 10 ? "0" + number : number;
}

console.log(getFormattedDate(new Date("2019-08-02T05:01:03Z")));
```

Comment: Thanks for you response. Is this really the easiest way of implementing "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm-ss"???

Comment: @Yas yes if you want to do it yourself. If you have to do a lot with dates I would recommend you a library.

Comment: @Yas if the answer is leads to the correct solution you may want to accept it so the question does not popup in the unanswered section anymore

Answer (score 0):

Use the following script to get the current date and time using JavaScript in “Y-m-d H:i:s” format

```js
var today = new Date();  
var date = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;
console.log(dateTime);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Avinash Receiving following error when saying:  "TypeError: datetime.getYear is not a function"

`var datetime = new Date(created_at).toLocaleString();
var date = datetime.getFullYear()+'-'+(datetime.getMonth()+1)+'-'+datetime.getDate();
var time = datetime.getHours() + ":" + datetime.getMinutes() + ":" + datetime.getSeconds();
var dateTime = date+' '+time;`

Comment: @Yas The toLocaleString() method converts a Date object to a string.

Comment: This gives me the output: YYYY-m-dd, but how do i format it to YYYY-mm-dd?